# AddThis shows non-specified extra service in the compact menu

Tags: javascript, addthis

I have an AddThis compact share button on my page. The services I used in the `addthis_config` variable are `facebook, twitter, email`. However, for some of the users there's a **Tumblr** share displayed in the dropdown as well, which I never specified.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="addthis_button_compact js-addthis-btn">
    <span>Share</span>
</a>
```

**JS config**

```
window.addthis_config = {
    services_compact: 'facebook, twitter, email',
    services_expanded: 'facebook, twitter, email',
    ui_click: true, // Compact menu shows only on click
    ui_offset_top: 5
};
```

Why does Tumblr share magically appear in the dropdown for some users and not for others?

Answer (score -1):

If you only specify three services within services_compact, the remaining services will be filled in as the user's preferred services. AddThis doesn't provide a way to only show three services within services_compact.

An alternative approach if you only wanted three services to be available would be to disable the compact menu that appears on hover by setting ui_click to false.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but you're wrong. `services_compact` **can** be limited to only 3 values. And `ui_click` disables hover when set to **true**, not **false**. At least according to the docs: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1337994-the-addthis_config-variable

Comment: Sorry @matt but that's not what the docs say - http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1337994-the-addthis_config-variable